# Rebasing against a remote branch that was push forced

Tags: git

I have a remote branch on a git server where another developer git push forced a his master branch onto. I have a local master branch right now that I am trying to merge my master branch with the remote master branch. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, backup your current master branch

```
git checkout master && git branch master_bkp
```

Next, fetch the updated changes

```
git fetch
```

Now rebase branch your local master branch onto the fetched `origin/master` branch

```
git rebase origin/master
```

If you had comits on your master branch earlier, that you would like to bring into this freshly pulled master branch, you can [cherry-pick them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9339429/1860929)

Comment: The wording in "Now rebase the fetched `origin/master` branch onto your local master branch" is backwards: you're rebasing your local work onto the fetched branch.