# Does cherry-pick remove the commit from the origin branch?

Tags: git

suppose I have cherry-picked the commit `comm1` from the `master branch` into `branch foo`. Will the commit `comm1` be removed from the `branch master` after successful cherry-pick or it will be just copied into `branch foo`?

Comment: [A copy: cherry-pick is a new commit applying the same diff elsewhere](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Comment: It will create new commit on foo branch and leave master intact. If you want more details check docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It will copy the commit's delta and create a new commit out of it in the active branch.

When you ask yourself questions about what `Git` will modify or not, keep in mind that you can only modify the active branch. So if your active branch is `development` and you are cherry-picking a commit from branch `feature/test`, you can only modify `development` and not `feature/test`. This way, you can deduce that the commit in `feature/test` will not be affected.

Comment: Not the commit's content, the commit's delta to is predecessor.

In my opinion this is a huge difference.

Cherry-Picking a commit containing file1 file2 file3 and adding file4 won't create file1-3 in a branch that does not contain them. It will only add file4 to this branch.

Remember, commits are always snapshots of the whole repository, no delta.

Comment: @BlackEye Thank you for correcting. In my head it's clear that what I call the commit's _content_ is the delta but it is the wrong terminology and it may confuse new git users.

Answer (score 6):

Simply saying it will merge the particular change (commit) into target branch. Merge doesn't affect the source branch so it will be definitely not deleted.

So when you do full merge later, git will already know that this change was already integrated and will skip it.