# What does cherry-pick do?

Tags: git

```
a1----a2----a3-----a4 (branchA)
      \
       \b1---b2---b3---b4----b5----b6 (branchB)
```

current I am in `branchA(a4)`, if I do `git cherry-pick b3`

what happens? diff of b3 and b2 will be patched to a4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Comment: It does what the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_rebase_cherry_pick) says it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no conflicts, then the history after `cherry-pick b3` will be:

```
a1----a2----a3-----a4----b3' (branchA)
      \
       \b1---b2---b3---b4----b5----b6 (branchB)
```

where `b3'` is the same change as `b3` but rebased against `branchA`.

If you have any conflicts, then the `cherry-pick` command will tell you so and prompt you to resolve the conflicts manually before committing `b3'`.

In particular, doing a `cherry-pick b3` does *not* include the changes `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: `b3' is the same change as b3` means `diff of b3 and b2` or `diff of b3 and a2`?

Comment: @Sato: The "change" in `b3` is the difference between `b3` and `b2`. As I said, the changes made in `b1` and `b2` are not involved in the cherry-pick.