# git cherry-pick does not just pick the diff of the commit

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have two branches: `A` and `B`.

- `A`'s commit history: `a <- b <- c`;
- `B`'s commit history: `a <- h <- i`;

Assume that there is only one file here.

1. In commit `b`, I adds some texts like "foo".
2. In commit `c`, I adds some texts like "bar".
3. Then I `git cherry-pick c` on `B` branch. I thought `cherry-pick` will only pick the changes in `c` to branch `B`. However, it will add both `foo` and `bar` to branch `B`. Which is obviously not what I want.

Therefore, `cherry-pick` will pick all the changes of those files touched in commit `c` since the ancestor commit `a`. Is that right? What if I only want to pick the diff from `b` to `c` and apply it onto `i`?

## Update the exact steps

1. Init a git repo;
2. Add file `test.txt` and issue the first commit `init commit`. `test.txt` is now:

   ```
   first line  
   second line
   ```
3. Create a new branch `dev` but stay in branch `master`;
4. Add `added in commit b` to the file and issue the commit `b`. `test.txt` is now:

   ```
   first line
   added in commit b
   second line
   ```
5. Add `added in commit c` to the file and issue the commit `c`. `test.txt` is now:

   ```
   first line
   added in commit b
   added in commit c
   second line
   ```
6. Check out `dev` branch and issue the commit `h`. `test.txt` is now:

   ```
   first line
   second line

   adding by commit h
   ```
7. `git cherry-pick <commit c SHA1 ID>` to cherry-pick commit `c` onto commit `h`.
8. The conflict message:

   ```
   index 6a8dc57,594c6ec..0000000
   @@@ -1,4 -1,4 +1,9 @@@
     first line
   ++<<<<<<< HEAD
   ++=======
   + added in commit b
   + added in commit c
   ++>>>>>>> 06ce9b1... commit c adding another line
     second line
    +
    +adding by commit h
   ```
9. See? `cherry-pick` also brings the changed in commit `b`.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean

Comment: @ArunG Thanks! I know what `cherry-pick` means. But I am just confused that it is not equal to getting the diff of that commit and applying the diff to the target branch. It also contains contents **NOT** in that commit.

Comment: @tamlok, run `git show a` (replacing `a` with the relevant commit SHA obviously) to inspect the changes that commit will actually introduce to see why you might be getting deltas from commit `b`. You can always run `cherry-pick` with the `-n` flag to stop and manually trim away unwanted changes as well.

Comment: Please show the exact sequence of commands (including what you are using to display the cherry-picked commit). I think you misinterpret what you are seeing.

Comment: @MikeMB Please see the updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` tries to bring just one commit. But it does this by applying a patch which requires some context. The change done in commit C is very close to the change done by commit b, so you get the conflict - it can't just find the correct place where change has to be applied. And when you have conflict, you also get some of the conflicting context which is at least a part of your commit B.

Here's how it would work without the conflict:

```
$ git init
$ cat > f
line1
line2
line3
$ git add f
$ git commit -a -m "initial"
# Edited to add a line in the beginning of f
$ cat f
Commit b
line1
line2
line3
$ git commit f -m "B"
# Edited to add a line in the end of f
$ cat f
Commit b
line1
line2
line3
Commit c
$ git commit f -m "C"
$ git checkout HEAD^^
$ git cherry-pick master
$ cat f
line1
line2
line3
Commit c
```

Comment: So `git cherry-pick master` will just pick commit `c` instead of both `b` and `c`? That is when using a branch name with `git cherry-pick`, it will only pick the last commit? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried `git cherry-pick master`. The result is the same, the conflict content still contains the changes in commit `b`. :(

Answer (score 1):

> What if I only want to pick the diff from b to c and apply it onto i?

You can find/write the `diff` of a file between two commits (`c..d`). Then apply that in your current branch.

```
$ git checkout <B-branch>

# write the diff in a file named 'change.patch' (root directory) 
$ git diff <b-commit> <c-commit> <file-name> >> ~/changes.patch

$ git apply ~/changes.patch       # apply the changes
$ git add .

# merge the changes to i (previous commit)
$ git commit --amend -m 'Apply the diff of b and c'

$ git push -f origin HEAD      # force(-f) push since history is changed
```

Comment: I know this "original" way. But according to `git cherry-pick`'s description, why will it also pick extra changes from other not-specified commits? Thanks!

Comment: In my case, the patch does not cleanly apply, so I have to use the `--3way` option for a three-way merge. Then I get the exact same result as with using `git cherry-pick`, except there the error is muted and it seems to fall back to three way with no heads up. I still don't see why the three way merge end up with that result, but my two branches have diverged a lot so that may be relevant.