# How to merge a branch on Git when master has changed - need to issue pull request on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a branch (developer) based on master, I have been working on this branch and another developer made 2 commits to master, so I am now 2 commits behind master, but 10 commits ahead on my branch.

The 2 commits on master are actually irrelevant to me as I have made changes to the code that they relate to, so my branch is more up to date.

I have to issue a pull request on GitHub to have my (developer) branch merged, but as it stands, my branch will cause conflicts on GitHub, so I am looking for a clean way to sort out my branch so that I can issue a pull request on GitHub, and not have conflicts.

Any Git experts out there have any advice for me please?

Comment: `git fetch; git rebase origin/master`.  You will resolve the conflicts so that your changes apply to the current state of master and can be merged.

Answer (score 1):

While on the **developer** branch, try `git pull origin master`, fix the conflicts (if any) then commit and push the changes to the **developer** branch.

Answer (score 0):

Besides merging (by pulling) as has been already pointed out, you could also "rebase" your branch so that it "looks like" it was developed on top of the current position of the remote branch:

`git fetch <remote-repo>
git rebase <remote-repo>/master`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just to be clear as my remote is master at GitHub and my local branch is developer, branched off the master pulled from GitHub, could you be explicit with the commands so that I'm certain what I'm going to be doing please? I.e. what should I have checked out when I start these commands?

Comment: The thing is that the remote could have _any_ name. If you cloned (like from a github repo), it's origin, but it's not mandatory. If you created an empty repo locally then added the github remote, it could have any name. If your github remote is called 'origin', then it'd be (having already checked out your local branch that you want to 'update' with whatever is on origin/master): ```git fetch origin; git rebase origin/master```

Comment: Ok thanks, I kind of get it, I cloned the repo from GitHub, git remote -v shows origin I did a git checkout -b developer to create my branch, worked on it, and someone else worked on master at GitHub, so I am assuming while I am on the developer branch, if I git fetch origin; git rebase origin/master this will add my developer commits to the end of the latest master commits (that the other developer did), and I'd be able to then  git commit -am "Commit message" to have my branch ready to push up to GitHub, and issue a pull request.  - Thanks so much for your time

Comment: If you rebase, there's no need to "commit" anything at the top. If you have 10 commits on your 'developer' branch, you will end up with your local developer branch with 10 commits on top of origin/master and then you could *push*.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for your help, and your time

Answer (score 0):

There is git cherry-pick feature. You can commit the commit in other branch to your branch using commit ID. For details

[What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean/39119678#39119678][1])

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it, I need to get more familiar with Git, been stuck in SVN for far too long.

Comment: cherry-pick is the swiss army knife of version control (it even exists in svn, with merge -c option). git-rebase (which is another very powerful tool in and of itself) is based on it, as a matter of fact.