# GIT: Creating new branch with reverted changes

Tags: github, gitlab, git-commit, git

Accidentally I merge branch on my master branch but I had to revert the changes. I want to create a new branch and pick all the changes I had to revert.

Any of you knows how can I create the branch with all my previews commits?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: `git cherry-pick`

Comment: See the accepted answer on [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339460/5395709)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create and checks out a new branch:

`git checkout -b [name]`

To [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) a commit onto this new branch:

`git cherry-pick [commit hash]`