# How push approved commits from one branch to another branch in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, branching-and-merging, git-commit

I have two branches in bitbucket and I want to push only some commits (which are approved by me) from one branch to another branch which is a master branch.
Can someone explain to me how I can do it in the bitbucket environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **git cherry-pick**

## steps

```
1. git log 
  this will list all commits take the commit id which you wanted to move.
2. git cherry-pick <commit-id>
  apply this after switching to master branch
3.then push new master to remote
  git push  <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME> 
  eg. git push origin master
  or 
  git push  <REMOTENAME> <LOCALBRANCHNAME>:<REMOTEBRANCHNAME> 
  eg:
    if my remote name is heroku and i want to push local heroku branch to heroku(remote) master barnch(heroku/master) 
    git push heroku heroku:maste
```

## links

[What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Comment: @ suhail areekkan, may I ask you what is command for the third step?