# Merging the changes included by only one commit in my branch?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I use to work with a partner and each of us works in a parallel branch.

Sometimes, I want to merge some change that he have commited but I do not want to merge all the commits that are in his branch.

If I merge his branch, I will merge the commit that is pointed out by his branch and all this ancestors. It is not I want.

If I merge a specific commit, I will merge that commit and all this ancestors. It is not I want.

How can I merge the changes included by only one commit in my branch without merging his ancestors?

Explanation: My partner works in their files and I work in mine. But sometimes, one of us changes a file that is common for both, so we need to merge only the change that was made in the commom file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cherry-pick` is indeed what you want in this case. It allows you to specify a commit hash to apply on to your current branch:

`git cherry-pick <commit>`

When merging branches in with cherry-picked commits, git should be able to fast-forward over these commits, ensuring you don't end up with duplicated commits.

One problem with this flow is if a problem is discovered in a commit that has been cherry-picked. The change would need to be applied to both your branches.

A recommendation from me would be rather than cherry-picking commits, merge those commits in to your main branch. This makes it much easier for you both to keep up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I think cherry pick is what you are looking for:

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339460/3790546