# Using older commit in different branch

Tags: git

I have had two feature branches, that have been requested to merge at some point. Now i need to use one of the commits after the merge just for one branch. Is there easy way how to move this commit to the other branch? (As far as i have checked the files pushed in this commit are not changed in other commits after merge)

Comment: You can use `git cherry-pick <commit-id>` to create a new commit that contains the same changes as the commit with id <commit-id>.

Comment: You can cherrypick , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean

Comment: Sorry @prudviraj I didn't see the link you posted. --- OP, are you aware what you need to do now?

Comment: You can cherry pick it but you'll encounter merge conflicts (or worse, some changes will be ignored or reverted without triggering a conflict) on merge. Read this [series of articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180312-00/?p=98215) about how to merge instead of cherry-pick to solve such situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cherry-pick. If you want to have commit from one branch to targeted branch then use cherry-pick.

```
git cherry-pick:

checkout/switch to your targeted branch.
> git checkout <targeted branch>

Then use cherry-pick:
>git cherry-pick <commit id>
note: <commit id> is the commit id of another branch you want to use in your 
targeted branch .

Ex:
git cherry-pick f1f17bc7cd4799377a7dbc39211b0f0a5820bf92
```