# What does "git cherry-pick origin/master" mean?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

What does `git cherry-pick origin/master` mean? How does this instruction work?

When updating current local master branch from remote (i.e., fetch data from remote and merge with local files), we could use the following options:

- `git pull origin master`
- `git fetch origin master; git merge origin/master`
- `git fetch origin master; git rebase origin/master`
- `git fetch origin master; git cherry-pick origin/master`

But I cannot understand `git cherry-pick origin/master` and cannot find the explanation.

I am curious about the following things: when I use `git fetch origin master; git cherry-pick origin/master` to try to update current local master branch from remote, this action compares previous commits and brings the different parts as modified files, so I can use one commit to includes these modified parts. How does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Answer (score 4):

While `merge` and `rebase` work with multiple commits by default, `cherry-pick` operates on only one commit by default. The cherry-pick command above will not include all commits from `origin/master` unless specified (or if there's only one additional commit between `origin/master` and local `master`).

Issuing `git cherry-pick origin/master` will take the single commit at the tip of `origin/master` and apply it to the current working branch.

In addition to how the three commands operate with commits, there are other differences which can be found by looking at the `git` documentation.

This is a good explanation of `cherry-pick`: [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Comment: Technically, `git merge` *also* takes a single commit besides the current `HEAD` commit, from which it computes a third commit; it then uses those three commits (only) to produce its result. But the process makes s a merge commit, with two parents, which makes it act like it took all the intermediate commits into consideration (but it really didn't!).