# How to move the base commit my branch inherit from to be the first commit in current branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How to make x-branch

```
feature/name          D - E - F
                  /
develop A - B - C
```

look like this

```
feature/name      C - D - E - F
              /
develop A - B
```

and move C to be the first commit on y-branch

**EDIT**
Sorry for the typo. 
Here is a brief scenario to what I need

> Here is the situation, I forgot to create a new feature branch from the develop and commit changes to develop and then released that I am on develop so I created feature branch and continued the work. So I want to reset the develop branch and keep all the work on feature branch

Comment: Do you want to delete `x-branch` and move commits? or it was typo in branch name?

Comment: Sorry for the copy past mistake 

Comment: Here is the situation, I forgot to create a new feature branch from the develop and commit changes to develop and then released that I am on develop so I created feature branch and continued the work. So I want to reset the develop branch and keep all the work on feature branch

Comment: Edited, if any more let me know 

Comment: Have you pushed changes to remote or not ? Commit C is in local only ?

Comment: Till now I only pushed feature and commit C is on my local only

Comment: I have a kind of hack. Do you need that ?

Comment: Sure, maybe help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your diagram correctly, you want to move your `develop` to point to `B` instead of `C`.

To do this locally:

1. `git checkout B`
2. `git branch -D develop`
3. `git checkout -b develop`

Of course, if you want to apply the same changes to a remote repo, you'll also need to delete the remote `develop`, (`git push --delete`) and recreate it (`git push`).

Update: minor note:

Judging from the comments and the other answer, it seems there's a misunderstanding of how git branches work. To put it simply the branch `feature/name` does NOT consist of commits `D`, `E`, and `F`. It consists of all 6 commits `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is or other examples for more thorough explanations.

Comment: How mistakes are contagious :-) Did *you* also make a typo? Because it would be y-branch to modify, x is not to change here... then again, question is awfully unclear, and OP does not bother to answer or clarify...

Comment: @MohamedAbuGalala Fair enough, now you're here :-)

Comment: No problem  I post from mobile so it's hard a little 

Comment: seems `y-branch` (top-branch in graph) is unchanged, and `x-branch` (bottom branch in graph) is modified. I recall pre-edit they were both labeled x-branch in the bottom graph, so I went by the labels of the top-graph. let me know if my interpretation of the graphs is incorrect.

Comment: Yea you did not understand the question well as I made a typo mistake. Sorry for that 

Comment: after ur edit, my answer still holds. i've updated branch names to match ur new branch names for clarity, but the answer is the same. 1. Delete old develop branch, 2. checkout the last commit u want on ur develop branch, 3. create new develop branch

Comment: I don't want to touch history on develop branch.

Comment: u want to not exclude commit `C` from the develop branch. that's what this does. other commits will retain their same sha numbers and history is unchanged (other than removing C from develop branch.) See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is for clarification.

Comment: This link help me more to understand how git works  but I really don't understand how your solution helps me, but as you say and demonstrated in the link this means branch feature/name is consist of all commits. But this doesn't make any sense, cause I can push to master only branch feature/name and keep commit C on my local, so where commit C live if I clone the project again? It's not on develop sure but I can't find it on git log  so how branch feature/name have commit C?

Comment: I will try this in a simple repo and inform if any updates 

Comment: Hey, I tried both on a demo git repo with a readme.MD file only and both works correctly, but your solution is better because it solves the problem directly without any workarounds. Great thanks for both of you, I'm glad, this question made me understand Git better than I can imagine 

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a new branch `feature/name2` from commit B from develop branch. Then copy all commits to it and delete the old `feature/name` branch.

See if this helps.

```
# Go to commit B
git checkout <B commit id>

# Create a new branch from Commit B
git checkout -b "feature/name2"

# Copy all commit (D to F) to this new branch.
git cherry-pick <C commit id>
git cherry-pick <D commit id>
git cherry-pick <E commit id>
git cherry-pick <F commit id>

#If you want you can delete the old branch using (use with caution)
git branch -D feature/name

# To delete commit C from develop branch
git checkout develop
git reset HEAD~
```

From remote you can delete the old feature branch after pushing this new branch. You can rename this branch to `feature/name` also after deleting both local and remote `feature/name` branch.

Comment: Maybe this is the best answer I can think of. If there a better way will be great 

Comment: Sure !! I would also love to know.

Comment: But I think cherry-pick is copying the reference of the commit not a full copy I guess 

Comment: It will copy the changes. Commit ids will be different of source and copied commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean

Comment: how does this help? it does nothing but clone feature/name to feature/name2. They r still the same exact branch, and develop branch still includes commit C.

Comment: it will copy commit C in new branch feature/name2. now if you want you can delete commit C from develop branch

Comment: commit C is already in feature/name. How r feature/name2 and feature/name any different? why couldn't u just delete commit C from develop branch before u created the clone branch feature/name2?

Comment: In feature/name Commit C is common between development and feature branch. In feature/name2 Commit B is common between development and feature branch.

Comment: commit B is in all 3 branches, feature/name, feature/name2, and develop.

commit C is in both feature branches, but not in the develop branch.

so my question still stands, why did u clone feature/name renamed to feature/name2?

just because because u didn't cherry-pick B into feature/name2 doesn't mean it's excluded from feature/name2.

Comment: I will try this in a simple repo and inform if any updates 

Comment: @MohamedAbuGalala did you try this out ?

Comment: Hey, I tried both on a demo git repo with a readme.MD file only and both works correctly, but @junvar solution is better because it solves the problem directly without any workarounds. Great thanks for both of you, I'm glad, this question made me understand Git better than I can imagine 