# Remove line that does not exist in current branch

Tags: git

I am working in branch let say `b1`. The main branch that is to be deployed is let say `stage`. I forked my `b1` branch from `master` - this is our convention.

So here is the situation. I am currently in `b1`. In one file, I will call it `users.txt` there is a snippet that looks like this:

```
print("Hello user")
print("Bye user")
```

In `stage` branch the same snippet looks like this:

```
print("Hello user")
print("You are welcome")
print("Bye user")
```

Now in my working (`b1`) branch I am suppose to make such change that when merged to `stage` will remove this line: `print("You are welcome")` and make the `stage` branch look like it. In other words after executing `git checkout stage` `git merge b1` - the `stage` file `user.txt` to look like this:

```
print("Hello user")
print("Bye user")
```

In yet other words: Remove line in branch `stage`, by making the change in branch `b1` where the line that is to be removed does not exist in `b1` in the first place.

One caveat: I am not allowed to merge `stage` into `b1` by convention(to be honest - I don't understand)

Comment: How was `stage` created?  Was it also forked from `master` and got progressed independently?

Comment: Yes, Stage is changed vial merge from multiple development branches like `b1` and somewhere, by some merge this line appeared `print("You are welcome")`. So I am suppose to remove that line, but THAT line simply does not exist in my development branch `b1`

Comment: Ideally your development branches should be forked from `stage`. You should keep `master` for mirroring production code. Merging independent `dev` branches forcefully into `stage` will simply override previous `dev` branch chages which does not make much sense.

Comment: Probably you are right. The circumstances are strange here I admit. I asked the same question:

Me:
so can I merge STAGE to the my b1 branch?

Boss:
No. It will make it not possible for me to make an isolated deploy then. But you can merge the branch where this feature presents.

Comment: Does [cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean) work for you?

Comment: For such cases, deployments should be done from your feature branches directly. Not by merging it to stage. This needs a fix in your deployment pipeline. I hope you have a single member team. Otherwise i can imagine the chaos happening in your team.

Comment: @Theraot

I think it will. I will go for your approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Disclaimer for obsolete answer : question was edited after my answer, now `stage` shouldn't be merged into the feature branch)*

---

Since `b1` and `stage` have different initial states for the `users.txt` file, you'll first have to update `b1` to catch up with recent changes, namely the new line it lacks.

```
git checkout stage
git pull
git checkout b1
git merge stage
```

At this point you might (or not) have to resolve conflicts. Then your `users.txt` will be similar to the one on `stage`. Just delete the line, add and commit :

```
# go delete the line in "users.txt" then...
git add path/to/users.txt
git commit -m "Deleted said line"
```

---

**Edit after your comment about no merging stage into features**

If you can't merge `stage` in, but are allowed to merge the feature the line originated from, go for it. You'll have to locate which commit it comes from :

```
git log -1 --oneline -S "Copy the text of the line here"
```

This will output the last commit which touched the line. Note its hash. You can then import that commit in your branch with a cherry-pick, as hinted at by Theraot in comments.

```
git cherry-pick <commitHash>
```

Comment: Yes it would do the job for me, but my Boss does not allow to merge `stage` to our development branches. I assume, what I am asking for here might not be possible at all, but I have to be sure there is no decent way to do that before I get into an argument with my boss