# How Can I replace/copy all file and folder from one branch to another existing branch in GIT

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have 3 branch -> `Master`, `develop` and `admit_card`. I had created before `admit_card` from the `develop` branch. I always made changes on `admit_card` branch and merge it into `develop`.

But suddenly I have changed some more files and also deleted folder form the `develop` branch. And now I want to copy/keep updated to the `admit_card` branch like `develop` branch (By deleting folders and files).

I merged it with `develop` branch. It is merging with `develop` branch properly. But the issue is the folders and files I deleted from the `develop` branch is still showing into the `admit_card` branch.

here is the merge develop branch with `admit_card` branch.

```
git checkout admit_card
git merge develop
```

what should I do please? How can I copy/replace exact `develop` branch to `admit_card` branch? Can anybody please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Try [cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean) from `develop` to `admit_card`

Comment: @SubrataMondal Thank you for your help. I have tried cherry-pick. But it is showing this error.

**error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:**
Files.....
Aborting
fatal: cherry-pick failed

after using this command
`git checkout admit_card`
`git cherry-pick -x develop`

Comment: First 
`git add .`
`git commit -m "Before cherry pick from development"`

Into `admit_card`. Then cherry pick

Comment: @SubrataMondal It is showing this message 
**Performing inexact rename detection: 100% (188544/188544), done.
On branch admit_card
You are currently cherry-picking commit 5221a7b.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset'**

when I am trying to run this code
`sudo git cherry-pick develop`

Answer (score 0):

I think `rebase` is better approach here.

On your `admit_card` branch run

`git rebase develop`

This will, in effect, set your `admit_card` branch to the contents of the `develop` branch and then play back any additional commits on the `admit_card` branch on top of this. You might have merge conflicts if you have touched the same files in both the branches. Once you resolve the merge conflicts, your `admit_card` branch will be a clean topic branch on top of your develop branch again.

Run `git rebase --abort` if you get stuck with the merge to revert back to how things were.

Comment: Hi @idlethead, Thank you. But I think, this will replace the commit history too. I can not get back to the older commit, if I use "rebase". right?

Comment: You can, using git reflog. In your question you asked "How can I copy/replace exact develop branch to admit_card branch?" rebase is the answer. You are in this situation because you changed your develop and admit_card branch together - if you'd committed changes from admit_card to develop before you deleted some files there, you wouldn't face these issues.

Comment: Hi @idlethead, Thank you for you suggestions. But I committed both admit_cart and develop branch. 

And for the clearance, yes I want to replace the current status(replace folder, deleting folders and files etc) from develop branch to admit_card branch but admit_card commit history. So that if I need to role back anytime to another commit, I can move to the commit. Hope you understand my issue.

Let me know if there is any solution please. Thank you

Comment: You only have two options afaict. Use `git merge` and deal with the merge conflicts or `git rebase` and rewrite branch history on admit_card. In both cases, `git reflog` will allow you got go back to an older version. You can even tag the current state of the two branches to make it easier to checkout the original versions at a later time.