# Git rebase from master to dev

Tags: git, rebase

I just wanted to ask this to make sure I am doing it correctly, as I don't want to screw up anything.

I created a feature branch (`feature1`) off of master and have worked on it. However, I really should have created the branch off of dev.

Is this as simple as doing the following?

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase dev
```

There are a couple extra things in dev than are not in master.

Comment: In theory, yes, but keep in mind that `feature1` has contents that _depend_ on the point where you branched off of `master`, and recreating its progress while branching off of `dev` instead may not be simple.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if there are revisions in _master_ that are not in _dev_ that _do not belong_ to your feature branch, they would be carried over.

Comment: @matt Right now, it appears `master` is essentially a subset of `dev`. In other words, `dev` is just `master` with some extra directories. If I were to do a `git rebase` and something went wrong, would that screw up only my feature branch, or the entire `dev` branch as well?

Comment: Nothing would "screw up" anything. Nothing is written on tablets of jade. Make safeguards.  Then try it and, if you don't like it, undo it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no collisions between `master` and `dev`, yes, it would be as simple as that.

If there are considerable conflicts between `master` and `dev`, it might be easier to create a new branch out of `dev` and [`cherry-pick`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9339429/2422776) your changes there.

Answer (score 0):

The way to move only the stuff related to your feature branch would be

```
git rebase --onto=dev master feature1
```

That way you are asking git to move the revisions from feature1 *skipping* all revisions that are included in master, and place them on top of dev.