# How to push a single file change to two branches using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, commit, tortoisegit

I'm currently making changes to an older version of my app for customers still on that version but I want to push the changes to another branch I'm working on as well.

Is there an easy way to do this in TortoiseGit without having to copy the files over manually to the next branch and then push again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously want to [cherry-pick](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html), there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416104/236871) that tells you how to do it.