# Git: Remove changes from Git commit that is in middle of branch

Tags: git

I have 3 commits: a, b & c

I need to remove the changes introduced by b, such that just a & c are left

What I've done so far is create a new branch from a, and then cherry picked in c

However, when I merged with the master it merged back in b

How do I avoid this merge?

Comment: This really depends on whether you have pushed your commits.  If they're only local, you can do many things.  However, if they've been pushed, you'll want to stick with `git revert`

Comment: Yes, they are all pushed remotely unfortuantely

Comment: Why is this post downgraded without any comment to go with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to pop up and trash away a "middle" commit in my master branch. How can I do it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757187/i-need-to-pop-up-and-trash-away-a-middle-commit-in-my-master-branch-how-can-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove B in `A --> B --> C`, do :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~ A
```

You will get the interactive rebase text. Just remove the line representing `B` and continue the rebase and B will be removed.

Note that this will change your history, and should generally be done only when you have not pushed these commits to remote.

If pushed, do `git revert B` to make a new commit `B'` which removes the changes done by.

Comment: `git revert B` gives error "Could not revert" for Git version 2.15 on Windows 8. I created a sample repo, and created 7 commits in it on master branch, for example, say, C1, C2, C3... C7. Now when i give `git revert C6` it throws error:-  

`$ git revert 57e70d8  
error: could not revert 57e70d8... C4
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
`
Did something change in latest versions of Git? Any pointers what am i doing wrong? @DJ180 @manojlds